# Creating GUI why drag and drop is worse than writing a code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

As the title says, why better programmers write the code to create a GUI element. E.g. jTable, I am noob and I am used to drag it from swing controls and drop it there on my panel. But smarter way is to create jPanel in the code, isn't it?

I can see one reason and it is that later in the GUI class I have easier access to it.

So the question is why is there both possibilities and which one is the right one and which one is more professional?

EDIT: I am not asking on your personal opinion I am asking what is better and for what reason. I want to know facts not opinions.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [What topic can I ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as this question is opinion based. I sometime code or use Netbeans for my UI needs, it all depends on what I'm doing.

Comment: Tell me how could I know it is subjctive question? I was just asking what is more professional not what do you prefer. Did you get me? Thank you

Comment: It does not really matter how you get the code, as long as it has the right result.  There is no way to answer the question because both ways are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely subjective, but many people stay away from gui builders for several reasons:

- They hide implementation details from you, which is bad for novices.
- The code they generate is not really meant to be fiddled with by humans, so going in and changing your code is much more difficult.
- Using a gui builder adds a dependency on that gui builder, which is generally a bad thing. What if that gui builder stops being maintained?

Again though, this is entirely subjective, and whether you use a gui builder or code it yourself is up to you and your context. This isn't really a question for SO.

Comment: It is not that entirely subjective. You answered my question pretty well by telling me those 3 points and any of those are not subjective because they are facts, aren't they?

Comment: Well, your question has been closed for being opinion-based, so there's your answer. I've given you *my* reasons for not liking gui-builders, and plenty of people agree with me. However, other people would argue that gui builders are good for getting something up and running. For example, the Java tutorials recommend the netbeans gui builder. I disagree with that entirely (again, novices should NOT use a gui builder), but that's what makes it subjective.